# How to only allow the user type numbers and comma in the qml textField?

Tags: qt, qml

I want print the value of textField, but I want that the user only can type numbers, "," and /

```
TextField {
    id: textField1
    implicitWidth: 200
    implicitHeight: 30
}
Button{
    onClicked:{console,log(textField1.text)}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, here's the working solution below.

```
 TextField {
    id: textField1
    implicitWidth: 200
    implicitHeight: 30
    validator: RegExpValidator{regExp: /^[0-9,/]+$/}
}

Button{
    onClicked:{console.log(textField1.text)}
}
```

To prevent a user from entering something use a text validator in Qt [Found here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-regexpvalidator.html). It makes use of RegEx so u have more control.

by doing this you completely prevent a user from being able to enter the characters you dont want.

Answer (score 0):

on android and ios devices use

```
inputMethodHints : Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly
```

in TextField to Open Keyboard on  Only number input That is includes decimal point and minus sign.
and Other inputMethodHints [TextFiled QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#inputMethodHints-prop)

and use Regex in Validator for add Restrictions on Input.

Example:

```
TextField{
    validator: RegExpValidator{regExp: /[0-9,/]*/}
}
```